# Is there a way to change the delete action on an existing instance of shared_ptr

Tags: c++

I have a function where I want a cleanup action done 90% of the time, but in 10% I want some other action to be done.

Is there some way to use some standard scoped control like`shared_ptr<>` so that initially it can have one delete action and then later in the function the delete action can be changed?

```
shared_ptr<T> ptr( new T, std::mem_fun_ref(&T::deleteMe) );
ptr.pn.d = std::mem_fun_ref(&T::queueMe);
```

Comment: Why not enforce your deletion strategies in your custom deleter itself?

Comment: I was just trying to avoid writing the custom deleter when I just need to choose (currently) between 2 member functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can change the deleter once the `shared_ptr` was created.

But why would you do that ? Usually, when you create an object, you know immediatly how it must be destroyed. This is not likely to change.

If you really must do some specific treatments, you still can provide a custom deleter which does special things depending on the required logic.

Comment: I've just thought of a reason, which is that you could conceivably want to replace the deleter with a new deleter that does what the old one does, *and* something else (such as notify a listener of the object destruction). But I'm pretty sure it's not feasible, if only because the deleter is in the control block, so you certainly couldn't replace it with a deleter with a different size. So like you say, the potential for this behaviour needs to be in the `shared_ptr` right from the start.

Comment: The use case I can think of is that you have a library that returns a std::tr1::shared_ptr and you want to move control to a std::shared_ptr and you're confident that the std::shared_ptr will outlast the std::tr1::shared_ptr. 

Awful? Absolutely.

Answer (score 10):

Not really - the standard for `shared_ptr` is written in such a way that the `Deleter` may be stored by value in control node (a special object that contains the reference counter, holds deleter, tracks weak pointers etc). The deleter is type-erased, but if you know the concrete deleter type somehow, you can use `std::get_deleter<Deleter>(ptr)`. With it you may access the deleter and change its state. Example:

```
struct A {};

struct deleter {
    void operator()(A* a) {delete a; }
    int m_state;
};

std::shared_ptr<A> ptr(new A(), deleter{});

std::get_deleter<deleter>(ptr)->m_state = 5;
```

And if you use just a function pointer for all deleters, then yes you can completely replace it, as all potential deleters use the same signature.

(Yes I know the question is 9 years old, but I've just faced this problem in 2020 and solved it like this. The possible reason for it is wrapping C pointers and objects from legacy code that manage ownership through raw pointers)

Answer (score 2):

There is a valid reason to need to change the deleter. Take this for example:

```
int foo( std::shared_ptr<double>& bar ) {
    ...
    std::shared_ptr<double> p( my_allocator<double>::allocate(), my_deleter<double>() );
    bar.swap(p); // this copies the deleter
    ...
}

int main( int, char** ) {
    std::shared_ptr<double> d;
    foo( d ); // d now has a new deleter that will be called when it goes out of scope
    ...
}
```

In this case the foo() function allocates a double* using some special allocator. It needs to free that memory in a special way also. The caller shouldn't need to know how to free the memory.

Comment: Nothing gets changed here. You're creating a new `std::shared_ptr`, and then using it like any other value object.

Comment: @kuba-ober: I see, I misunderstood his original question. You're right, he definitely wants to change the deleter for the managed pointer after it's been constructed rather than updating the deleter on an existing shared_ptr object (as the title says).

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>

struct A {
    ~A() {
        std::cout << "~A()" << std::endl;
    }
};

using DeleterCb = std::function<void(A* p)>;

struct ADeleter {
 public:
    explicit ADeleter(DeleterCb cb) :
        mDeleterCb(cb) {}
    ADeleter() = delete;
    ~ADeleter() = default;

    void operator()(A *a) {
        mDeleterCb(a);
    }
    
    void setDeleterCb(DeleterCb cb) {
        mDeleterCb = cb;
    }

 private:
    DeleterCb mDeleterCb;
};

int main() {
    auto sp = std::shared_ptr<A>(new A{},
        ADeleter([](A *p){
            delete p;
            std::cout << "deleter_1" << std::endl;
        })
    );
    
    std::get_deleter<ADeleter>(sp)->setDeleterCb(
        [](A *p){
            delete p;
            std::cout << "deleter_2" << std::endl;
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't make any sense, since there is any number of `shared_ptr`s managing the ownership of the value. You'd need to modify them all, and that's not feasible. Let's not forget that a control block is an implementation detail, so going "aha, but change it in the control block" won't work.

The delete actions should be controlled by the instance owned by `shared_ptr`, e.g.

```
class C {
...
  void (C::action*)() { &C::action1 };
  void action1();
  void action2();
  ~C() { (this->*action)(); }
};

void test() {
  std::shared_ptr<C> a;
  a->action = &C::action2;
  // action2 gets invoked once `a` falls out of scope
}
```